# Are there any recipes to get rid of text ouput of binary files in between human content?

Tags: text, full-text-search, nlp, web-crawler

In grabbing content from web pages (within `p` tags) occasionally between human text I see long blobs of stuff like:

```
ªjßûÞà&fnof;^_^\,_>xî¹Ág?;´Â¼ú8&#x17E;^S^R +^R ^A^R ^A^R ^A^R ^A&rsaquo;^DÆ^Z^_&#x17D;m&rdquo;A&þÅ^R^N&OElig;^RÝmîÜaÎ^W¿¸;^Oéµk^G&Yuml;ÿü`ß}^G^G^\0¸ì²  &Yuml;b1oÞà#^_^Y&#x17D;EO9eâ?&#x17D;<ÅFw#^R     9æè^Q^AZß&ª¿lÙ`×®Ý¡wî^\&dagger;Â* &circ;&Scaron;«MB^BtE^B$@^B$@^B$@^B$`&ldquo;&euro;&#x17D;ýüÄ¬Y»Çª&tilde;òÅ^XrÉ&rsquo;Á;Þ1Ì¹þúÝ&ndash;[¶^LÞ÷¾Áyç^M×o`Åõ&lsquo;G^N°ôzÊ&rdquo;¡?N^W^Ow^F&fnof;iÓ^F0>ä?azæL?Ð0wàg^V&#x17D;Z^S&rsquo;^\^Y·µê?öØ°úc¾O&scaron;?^@]&lsquo;^@  ?^@     ?^@     ?^@     Ø$0r¤&Scaron;¡òA^G^MÇ?7Þ¸Ûæ&tilde;c&dagger;»:¤\¿~ðþ÷^O^^?}pÂ    Ã|^YÏc¬&#x17D;íS&Yuml;Ú]d¸3Ø={&OElig;!:¶C^Oõ#^Nsí^MÔ[«>Ö«^?à^C&fnof;íÛ},m=ªØì&ndash;TE^B$@^B$@^B$@^B$P4>¼æ&scaron;á^PúÓ&Yuml;Þmó?ï^Lw±&circ;EÆ?'?48ç&oelig;a^ZÃuo{÷»wÛH¾ØoØ0ÜÛ^?ÿÝ&Dagger;t êÚhfa"a«ùbÜ¸-T^_Óéï|çàþû&lsaquo;d¸&rsquo;ö¤^S^R +^R ^A^R ^A^R ^A^R  &dagger;        `R:ü¯ywY&trade;Q_½:ÇÕÐz8J^\þ&Dagge
```

and

```
  `i=æºeÙpÁ&mdash;UêsÀÂo^LÑñþ^EÞyÁK    ø+¨X²^ß-=?^@    ?^@     ?^@     ?^@     ?À¤$&euro;Ñ2^[Æ\:^õ?&rdquo;^Ud¥H&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;^DH&euro;
```

My only familiarity with them is when I accidently open some binary files in a text editor. These are long sequences and are polluting my sample. Are there any techniques to get rid of them?

**PS:** What are they? For eg, some of them are accompanied by

```
endstream
endobj
37 0 obj
817
endobj
38 0 obj
<< /Length 39 0 R /N 3 /Alternate /DeviceRGB /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
```

Comment: You could use a language identifier, i.e. an algorithm that is normally used to detect what language a document is written in. But I suspect this is really a problem in the crawler or HTML parser. Perhaps you'd better find out which of the (alleged) HTML documents causes this problem and what can be done about it, or how to avoid parsing the document in the first place.

Comment: @jogojapan I added an if statement which rejects all pdf files. The only other major noise comes from inline javascript. But I'll leave that for another day.